# My DIVs are working differently since my site was deleted (by my awful Name host) & then re-UL'd

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery of images on my website. I had to alter a template I used to make it so that gallery showed images horizontally in rows of 3 or 4. I honestly don't recall how I did this, but when my Name host deleted my site recently (don't ask), and & re-UL'd my files, that gallery looked like it did when I first DL'd the template, and now I can't get the rows any longer.

I've tried commenting out some of the DIVs comparing what I have w/a similar mirror site, but I'm not seeing any change. The mirror site I set up differently so it's not as apt as I hoped it would be. Anyway, the gallery has images w/captions, and I've tried rearranging the info but to no avail. My temp fix is some really messy HTML on the actual site (therealitycomics.com -- gallery section, where there are currently just 5 images).

```
<footer id="footer"> 
<div class="inner">

<div class="gallery cf">
<div>
<a target="_blank" 
href="http://therealitycomics.com/images/Postcard.jpg">
<img src="http://therealitycomics.com/images/Postcard.jpg" alt="The 
Reality" width="155" height="220">
</a>
<div>How our Intraverse<br>connects</div>
</div>
<div>
<a target="_blank" 
href="http://www.therealitycomics.com/patreon/PK11.jpg">
<img src="http://www.therealitycomics.com/patreon/PK11.jpg" alt="Phantom 
Kid layout" width="155" height="220">
</a>
<div>Phantom Kid pg<br>Layout 1</div>
</div>
<div>
<a target="_blank" 
href="http://www.therealitycomics.com/patreon/PK11b.jpg">
<img src="http://www.therealitycomics.com/patreon/PK11b.jpg" alt="Phantom 
Kid layout" width="155" height="220">
</a>
<div>Phantom Kid pg<br>Layout 2</div>
</div>
```

I'n NOT a coder, I just used a template and figured out what changes I needed to make to build my site, so I'm not so great at the trouble-shooting. And, also, it's been so long, I no longer retain the info I !did! learn.

! So please, when you offer advice, be as basic in your descriptions as possible. =] !

Expected result: Those images would all appear in the same row, each one w/its caption.
Actual result: Each image is a row of its own, with the captions under each one.

The DIVs are causing this, but I don't quite get why they're causing it now but weren't before. I checked my main.css b/c I thought the Footer ID or the DIV class "inner" might be the cause based on definitions in the main.css, but I'm not seeing any width or border definitions that are relevant (to my eye), but ALSO when I remove the DIVs around each image and caption, everything jumps up onto one row. And a new row starts with each new DIV tag.

The site (w/its messed up gallery where I commented out all of the old gallery): TheRealitycomics.com
A URL where you can see it as it was: http://therealitycomics.com/indexB.html (again, this is the page where everything HAD been in rows of 3 or 4 but now is just one long column).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your `main.css`. It should set your gallery section so that it displays four items in a row (unless the browser window width is under 800px, then it will display only two items in a row).

```
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery > div {
    width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .gallery > div {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Janne answer is the best way to do it. But, if you don't want to use `.css` files (not recomended) you can inline the styles:

```html
<div class="gallery cf" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row;">
    <div style="flex-basis: 25%">
         <a target="_blank" href="http://therealitycomics.com/images/Postcard.jpg">
         <img src="http://therealitycomics.com/images/Postcard.jpg" alt="The Reality" width="155" height="220">
         </a>
        <div>How our Intraverse<br>connects</div>
     </div>
     <div style="flex-basis: 25%"> <!-- Other images -->
         ...
         ...
</div>
```

With `display-flex` property you tell the container that it should place elements in a unidimensional way, the dimension is set with the property `flex-direction` ("row" or "column"). With the property `flex-wrap` you say the container what to do when one child item exceed his container's size, with `wrap` value his children jumps to another line.

Property `flex-basis` only set the size of each child, 25% to get 4 children for each row, 33% to get 3, etc...

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this, like you said, since you would run into a lot of code duplication and things would get messy, when wanting to change the style of the images.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but he said that he isn't programmer, so maybe css classes and files could get him confused

Comment: Thank you both so much! I'm willing to dive into the CSS classes if you think it'll be best. So please feel free to offer the other option -- I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hi, I've finally had a chance to try making changes to the main CSS. It didn't go as I'd hoped but I was able to get things back so semi-normal. 

Per your instructions, I'm trying to avoid adding coding in index.html, but now I've new problems:

First: On the first row, I've two images that I'd *prefer* to be twice the length of the others. Now, of course, I can squish this back down to size, it'll be fine, but I'd prefer not to.


2nd: For a reason I cannot discern, the 2nd row has a big gap. The little black box image is NOT the cause (it's there as an easter egg for site visitors)

Comment: BTW: here's the code from the main.css for the gallery:

.gallery > div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
}

.gallery > div > img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  transition: .1s transform;
  transform: translateZ(0); /* hack */
}


gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery > div {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .gallery > div {
        width: 20%;
    }
}

.gallery > div:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.gallery > div:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.7,1.7);
  transition: .3s transform;
}

Comment: .cf:before, .cf:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

h1 {
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}